# Cannot create SDL2_ttf library correctly using local SDL2 repository using cmake

Tags: cmake, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I am making a project that has a `deps` folder with all its dependencies, currently it includes a git clone of SDL2 and SDL2_ttf. I'd like to get this project to work without having to install SDL2 or SDL2_ttf separately using home brew for example. My current approach is doing the follow, however, it seems like SDL2_ttf is failing to find the directory of SDL2, how can I fix it?

```
CMakelists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(app)

add_executable(app MACOSX_BUNDLE src/main.cpp)

# SDL2
add_subdirectory(deps/SDL2)
add_dependencies(app SDL2)

# SDL2_ttf
add_subdirectory(deps/SDL2_ttf)
add_dependencies(app SDL2_ttf)
```

Error message

```
CMake Error at deps/SDL2_ttf/CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSDL2.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2" with any of
  the following names:

    SDL2Config.cmake
    sdl2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SDL2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SDL2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SDL2"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

P.S. I tried doing `SET(SDL2_DIR deps/SDL2)` in my CMakeLists.txt as suggested in the error but that doesn't seem to be working, I get the same error message.

SDL2 does contain SDL2Config.cmake, I'm using the latest master of these repos:
https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL
https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf

Comment: Have you tried [`FetchContent`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FetchContent.html) for things like SDL_ttf that depend on SDL?